# GoogleAppEngine sign-in failed

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth

I am afraid I don't have much information on this problem, other than that I cannot deploy/update an application with GAE anymore.
  Every time when asked for email and password, I correctly enter them (as I always have done), and I get a Sign-in Failed message.

I tried it two ways, 1) with GoogleAppEngineLauncher application. I first get a panel saying: "Error, failed; auth error", and after I close this panel there is message in red in the sign-in panel, saying: Sign-in Failed. This is a hyperlink, which, when I click it, brings me to a browser page where I am asked to re-enter my password for my google-account. I enter the same password, and I get logged in normally.

If I click on the Dashbord button it brings me to the correct app-engine page of my application.

The second way is command-line:
    appcfg.py update /my_app_name

which results in:

10:48 AM Application: my_app_name; version: 1
10:48 AM Host: appengine.google.com
10:48 AM 
Starting update of app: my_app_name, version: 1
10:48 AM Getting current resource limits.
Email: my_email@gmail.com
Password for my_email@gmail.com: 
Invalid username or password.

However, I am 100% sure I am using the correct login details.

Well, I hope someone can make sense of this! thanks!

**edit**: this is the error panel I get when I try to deploy with the launcher app

[image: error]

Comment: try using the following flags --oauth2 or --noauth_local_webserver. If you're redirected to a Google OAuth screen is normal, it means your Auth token expired and you should renovate your permission from the project.

Comment: tnx Mario. I tried with --oauth2 flag, which presented me with an authentication webpage. So this way I can deploy using command-line, but using the GAELauncher doesn't work yet. Could you elaborate on "renovate your permission"? because the permissions page on appengine site doesn't mention tokens anywhere.

Comment: Have you tried what Julldar proposed?

Comment: I responded to Julldar just now. Do you agree with him that I should remove that file?

Answer (score 4):

You can visit https://www.google.com/settings/security and then enable "Access for less secure apps" . It works for me.

Answer (score 2):

You could try uploading with OAuth2:

> appcfg.py --oauth2 update /my_app_name

See for more info:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp#Python_Password-less_login_with_OAuth2

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, but I'm using maven to deploy, not appcfg. I know that I had to go in my "C/users/ME/" and delete a file called ".appcfg_oauth2_tokens_java", and it worked afterwards.

Having researched the issue, it seems to appear when you have multiple accounts logged in at some point. The system keeps a copy of one of your other accounts and tries to deploy using this. Deleting the appcfg_oauth token forced me to "re validate" my credentials

Comment: thanks for responding - I do indeed have two different google accounts that deploy projects. I checked the .appcfg_oauth2_tokens file, but I am a bit reluctant about deleting it without understanding why. I'll get back to this later.

Comment: well, I renamed the file, and then tried to deploy again with the Launcher app, but I get the same "Error, failed; auth error" panel.

Comment: Could you upload the screenshot with the error? Are you sure you're using the correct account for that project?

Comment: I added the screenshot above. I am sure about the account details, f.i. when I click on the "Dashboard" button, it brings me to https://appengine.google.com/dashboard?app_id=my_app_name, and there I am logged in with the correct account.