# GAE Authentication Failed, Enable Less Secure Apps

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm unable to deploy an app with Google App Engine due to authentication failure. This problem has been discussed a few times recently,

[GoogleAppEngine sign-in failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26013229/googleappengine-sign-in-failed/26114589#26114589)

[Deploy app in google app engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25223736/deploy-app-in-google-app-engine)

with a common solution being that you need to make a change to your google account to allow "less secure" applications to access (https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps). I'm fairly certain this is the problem in my case, as I received a message from google immediately after I tried to deploy with a warning that a 'less secure' third party app had tried to log in to my account.

My question is why are apps from GAE considered 'less secure' by google? I've deployed apps before without this problem, so do I need to update GAE? Should I be hesitant to enable 'less secure' applications, since surely there's accomanpying risk?

Answer (score 5):

Deploying your app with OAuth2 instead of passing in your username and password every time is probably a better idea.
You can do that with the --oauth2 option:

> appcfg.py --oauth2 update myapp/

See for more info:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp#Python_Password-less_login_with_OAuth2